# Is there a benefit to using both strong and bold tags on the same text?

Tags: html, xhtml, html-email, backwards-compatibility, html-rendering

I recently came across an enterprise website using both <b> and <strong> tags around some text, which upon inspection was formatted in the following way with both `<strong>` and `<b>`:

`<strong><b>Just So We're Clear, This Text is Bold, Folks!</b></strong>`

I am wondering if this serves some purpose of backwards compatibility, or if it is merely sloppy coding; if there is some use case for using both, I would like to know as I have to design for people using outmoded hardware/software.

I work with coding emails... dryness is less important than getting the point across; if being extra explicit with a tag helps in some weird edge case, I'll consider it.

Comment: I did quite a few emails when I was working for marketing groups.  This site was always my single best resource for compatibility:  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/  The downloadable chart is amazing!

Comment: Maybe they were concerned that one of the tags would be deprecated someday since they're redundant :)

Comment: The semantics of the `<strong>` and `<b>` elements in HTML5 are neither mutually exclusive nor redundant, so it is conceivable that a string wrapped with both could be correctly marked up. But it's probably just poor coding.

Comment: For interest, http://jsfiddle.net/31ob55py/ is a jsFiddle which if opened in Firefox or IE (but not Chrome or Opera) shows a simple case where the text is only bold if it is in both elements. But it's still poor coding. If bolded text is required, CSS should be used to apply it.

Comment: Agreed with @Alohci. To answer the question of backwards compatibility: no, there is no browser or email client that supports only one of `<strong>` and `<b>`. In addition, since this question is tagged with XHTML, I just want to remark that, contrary to popular belief, `<b>` was never deprecated in XHTML.

Comment: Thank you all for these comments, which are quite interesting and in sum provide a some great insights! We support IE and have a lot of weird js libraries running (it's a mess), so @Alohci in particular: thanks! I would love to accept as an answer an the example that this could affect rendering in certain cases although declaring with css is far cleaner and more precise in terms of specifying font weights, although I note our mandated font stack degrades to Arial on most (i.e. Windows) machines so perhaps CSS is less useful for want of use of the greater precision of font-weight attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The w3 has [spelled out the use of `<b>` tags very clearly](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags)

Most telling:

> You should not use `b` and `i` tags if there is a more descriptive and
>   relevant tag available. If you do use them, it is usually better to
>   add class attributes that describe the intended meaning of the markup,
>   so that you can distinguish one use from another.